# Determining Published Versions of .apk files

Tags: google-play

How can I find the history for .apk files that I published to production?

I cannot find it in Google Play Console.

I used chat to talk to Google Play Console Rep.  They did not know.  They originally pointed me to the "Other Apks" section on the production tab.  I pointed out that this tab also contains the beta versions so it can not be the versions I released to production.

Answer (score 0):

1. We faced similar issue , very CRUDE way to doing this is going through Play Store Developer Console->statistics (select lifetime) and you can see all the releases and their versions on graph as shown below that were published and then use "Other Apk's" option suggested by Google to get further information.

Click on [image: Google Play Store->Statistics->LifeTime]

2. Another alternative is using third party site like https://www.appannie.com/

Comment: Do you now how to limit this report to just production?  See like it is doing production and beta.  My statistics are cluttered with Beta releases.